# add to a dictionary of list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

​​Hello all,

This is what I need help getting done in python.

to explain the context a bit:
I get processes related data repeatedly, at some fixed interval  (assume 10 seconds) which is info of all processes currently existing. (am mainly interested in the state)

I need to create data structure in python to basically store total time in each state for each process, each time I get samples (say every 10 seconds), so increment the state i find it in this time, if earlier record exists, or create new record for that state, etc.

So for each process, I need to maintain the state in a string, like "S","R","Z" or "UN" , and time in each state (increment same state, if process found in same state as last time, or add that state if first time process appeared in that state, or increment the state it is in now, if it was in that state previously and we had already created that record in the inner data structure )

I have a double dictionary,

```
process_state_info = {}
```

Then I get my sample at 10 seconds interval, say 3 processes running, in state like this showing me that since last 10 seconds, these pid's were in this state,

```
pid:1, state "S" 
pid:2, state "R"
pid 3, state "UN"
```

So this type of structure should be built

```
process_state_info = {1: [{"state":"S", "total_time": 10}],2:
[{"state":"R","total_time":10}],3:[{"state":"UN","total_time":10}]}
```

Each pid may come in different state in next samples, so i need to map pid to all possible states and time spent in those states.

for eg, if next sample gives me,

```
pid:1, state "R" ( changed state, so i need to add an entry in inner structure)
pid:2, state "R" ( in same state, so i will increment existing entry by10 seconds)
pid 3, state "Z" (changed state, add entry in inner structure)
pid 4, state "R" (new pid, add new outer structure)
```

So process_state_info will need to become

```
process_state_info = {1: [{"state":"S", "total_time": 10}, {"state":R", "total"time":10}],2:[{"state":"R","total_time":20}],3:[{"state":"UN","total_time":10}, {"state":"Z","total_time":10}], 4:[{"state":"R", "total_time":10}]}
```

I am pasting the code I'm trying, and the problem I'm having,

```
process_state_info = {} 

    for process in processes:
        found_pid = 0
        found_state = 0
        print "now process .. "
        print process.pid()
        for g_pid,g_state_info in process_state_info.items():
            if g_pid == process.pid(): #if we found the process already in our data structure
                print "found process in our data structure"
                found_pid = 1
                for state_iter in g_state_info:
                    print state_iter
                    if state_iter['state'] == process.s_name():
                        print "found state for the process in our data structure already"
                        #add interval to that record
                        current_total = state_iter['total_time']
                        state_iter['total_time'] = current_total + self.delta_time
                        found_state = 1
                        print "printing process table again"
                        print process_state_info
                        break
                if found_state == 0:
                    print "found pid but didnt find state inside, adding new state record"
                    inner_record = {"total_time":0,"state":""}
                    inner_record['state'] = process.s_name()
                    inner_record['total_time'] = delta_time
                    process_state_info[g_pid].update(inner_record)
                    print "printing process table now"
                    print process_state_info
                    break
        if found_pid == 0:
            print "didnt find it in our table"
            print "printing process table"
            print process_state_info
            inner_record = {"total_time":0,"state":""}
            inner_record['state'] = process.s_name()
            inner_record['total_time'] = self.delta_time
            g_pid=process.pid()
            print "gpid is"
            print g_pid
            process_state_info[g_pid].update(inner_record) # HOW TO ADD INNER RECORD ?
            print "printing process table again after adding new pid record"
```

output i get currently:

```
printing process table at start of function print_report
{}
now process .. 
1
didnt find it in our table
printing process table
{}
gpid is
1
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./pcp-pidstat.py", line 756, in <module>
    sts = manager.run()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pcp/pmcc.py", line 665, in run
    self._printer.report(self)   File "./pcp-pidstat.py", line 733, in report
    report.print_report(timestamp, header_indentation, value_indentation)   File "./pcp-pidstat.py", line 420, in print_report
    process_state_info[g_pid].update(inner_record) # HOW TO ADD INNER RECORD ? KeyError: 1L  <--- why does this happen, and why the "L" ?
```

Any suggestions .. python experts?

Comment: You may use tuples as dictionary keys, it may be useful. Something like: `process_state_info = {(1,'S'):10,(2,'W'):20}` where key `(1,'S')` means pid 1 state S and value `10` means total time.

Comment: aah so you mean i just need a dictionary , where the key is a tuple, and just an entry for total time. so you mean i dont need a nested dictionary at all ?

Comment: Yes, nested dictionary looks excesive.

Comment: how do i get rid of the "L" after the pid ? i think its a a long vs int thing, I get "L" appended to the digit in the key

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, `long` and `int` are separate data types. `1L` is the literal for the number one, expressed as a `long`. Numerically equal `long` and `int` values are nevertheless separate dict keys. Your `process.pid()` call is giving you a `long`, but the existing key in `process_state_info` was an `int`.

Comment: so do i need to cast it to int before calling update? and can i use update() to add a new inner record ?